# Prerendering OSM tiles with CartoCSS?

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik, cartocss

I've set up a PostGIS database and imported my map data. Then I ran

```
render_list
```

to render my tiles. Serving them through mod-tile works just fine. However, the files on my HDD are `*.meta` files and I would like to obtain `*.png` files in the standard z/x/y OSM format. How can I prerender my files?

From what I've seen, there's a python script called `'generate_tiles.py'` in this repository: https://github.com/openstreetmap/mapnik-stylesheets/blob/master/generate_tiles.py

I'm not entirely sure how to use it though. I also don't fully understand the difference between XML and CartoCSS and how it applies to my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually managed to resolve this. My problem came from the fact that I had installed mapnik via `pip install mapnik`. That installs a very old version of mapnik that doesn't work with the most current version of `openstreetmap-carto`. I eventually managed to get it to run with the following parameters to main of `'generate_tiles.py'`:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    home = os.environ['HOME']
    try:
        mapfile = os.environ['MAPNIK_MAP_FILE']
    except KeyError:
        mapfile = home + "/openstreetmap-carto/style.xml"
    try:
        tile_dir = os.environ['MAPNIK_TILE_DIR']
    except KeyError:
        tile_dir = home + "/osm/output/"

    if not tile_dir.endswith('/'):
        tile_dir = tile_dir + '/'
```

I have detailed the whole process on https://www.akaritech.com/prerendering-map-tiles-in-z-x-y-format/